# What is the measure I'm using called? Variant of Spearman's Rho

Tags: r, confidence-interval, simulation, ranking, spearman-rho

I've been simulating data to try to determine how best to select variables from a particular type of data set and I'm using a method I developed to determine what 'best' is, and I don't know what the method I'm using is called (if it has a name).

Initially I generate some binomial data that's pulled from a population that is correlated at a particular level, and remove half the data in a particular pattern:

```
    #generate probabilities
    p_vector <- rbeta(n, 40, 37.5)

    #generate outcome vector
    y_vector <- rbinom(n,1,0.5)

    #Generate n*n matrix of binomial P's
    p_matrix <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=n, ncol=n)

    for(i in 1:n){
      for(j in 1:n){
        p_matrix[j,i] <- p_vector[i]
    }}

    #For each row, change to inverse where Y vector is 0
    for(i in 1:n){
      for(j in 1:n){
        if(y_vector[j]==0){
          p_matrix[j,i] <- (1-p_matrix[j,i])
    }}}

    #Generate n x n matrix of binary data using this new matrix
    bin_matrix <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=n, ncol=n)

    for(i in 1:n){
      bin_matrix[,i] <- rbinom(n,1,p_matrix[,i])
    }

    #Remove data in characteristic data-loss pattern
    bin_matrix_loss <- bin_matrix

    for(i in 1:(n-1)){
      bin_matrix_loss[1:i,i+1] <- NA
    }
```

Once the data has been generated, I calculate correlations for each of the columns with the data that remains, and then use a fisher's z transform to get variance for these correlations. Once this is done, I calculate a lower bound on the confidence interval of the *absolute value* of the correlation to find those which have the highest absolute magnitude. I pick the m highest lower bounds and use those as the variables that I think have the highest true correlation with the y_vector.

```
    #Calculate r_xiy Correlation Matrix
    r_xy_vector <- numeric(0)

    for(i in 1:n){
      r_xy_vector <- c(r_xy_vector, 
    cor(bin_matrix_loss[!is.na(bin_matrix_loss[,i]),i],
                                  y_vector[!is.na(bin_matrix_loss[,i])]))
    }

    #Fishers z-transform
    z_prime <- (log(1+abs(r_xy_vector))-log(1-abs(r_xy_vector)))/2

    z_sd <- numeric(0)

    for(i in 1:n){
      z_sd <- c(z_sd, 1/sqrt(length(which(is.na(bin_matrix_loss[,i])==F))-3))
    }

    alpha <- 99/100 #this is the width of our confidence interval

    #Lower z-intervals
    z_lower <- z_prime-z_sd*qnorm(1-((1-alpha)/2))

    #Transform back into r
    r_lower <- (exp(2*z_lower)-1)/(exp(2*z_lower)+1)

    #Find the top m predictors
    best_predictors <- match(rev(tail(sort(r_lower),m)), (r_lower))
```

Now that I've found the best predictors I'm in the situation where I can compare these to the *true* top m predictors because the data is simulated. I'm using a comparison where I give each predictor a true rank, the highest being the best and the lowest being the worst, and sum up the rank of the predictors chosen and compare it to the best possible ranking. I'm using this as opposed to Spearman's Rho (between true best predictors and those chosen) because it doesn't suffer the issue that if the ranks are simply in the same order you get a perfect score, whereas with this method you just have to pick the m highest where order doesn't matter.

```
    #Compare this to the true top m predictors
    r_xy_vector_real <- numeric(0)

      for(i in 1:n){
        r_xy_vector_real <- c(r_xy_vector_real, cor(bin_matrix[,i], y_vector))
      } 

    best_predictors_true <- rank(abs(r_xy_vector_real), ties.method='first')

    matches <- best_predictors_true[best_predictors]

    score <-sum(matches, na.rm=T)/sum((n-m+1):n)
```

That little code chunks ranks the variables I picked, takes the sum, and compares it to the highest possible sum of scores (sum((n-m+1):n)).

Here's the question: Is the score I generate at the end a technique that's been used before? If so, what's it called?

Thanks for the help!